# run django local server than open chrome page in shell alias

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

I have an alias that's broken:

```
alias runautohelper='runproject autohelper 8009 & ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8009/bitbucket/create-repo'
```

Running the above gives

```
cchilders:~/projects/autohelper [master]$ runautohelper 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

But running:

```
alias runautohelper='runproject autohelper 8009; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8009/bitbucket/create-repo'
```

causes the server to start, and the second command (the page opening) doesn't run unless you quit the server. How can I run django server and open my page in one command, different subprocess? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it in background:

```
alias runautohelper='(runproject autohelper 8009 &) && (google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8009/bitbucket/create-repo &)'
```

Comment: this does not work, 

`cchilders:~/projects$ runautohelper 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: `alias runautohelper='runproject autohelper 8009 &; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8009/bitbucket/create-repo'`

Comment: oooooo I've never seen that in my life. ty let me try